# Filling a pandas dataframe with an increasing column offset for each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe where each row is filled with the same set of values but the starting column for each row increases by 1 for every row iterating down the dataframe. Here is my current approach, and an example of the dataframe I was hoping to get. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_to_fill = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((4,6)),columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6])

values_to_fill = pd.Series(np.arange(1,4))

# vars to iterate over dataframe
num_rows = len(df_to_fill)
# counter to keep track of how many columns to offset from to fill dataframe in loop below
col_offset = 0

for row in range(0,num_rows):
    # Fill the first row from first column onwards, 2nd from 2nd column onwards,...
    df_to_fill.iloc[row,col_offset:] = values_to_fill
    # Fill the remaining columns in the row with the last value from the values to fill series
    df_to_fill.iloc[row,:].fillna(values_to_fill.values[-1],inplace=True)    
    col_offset += 1

offset_array = np.array([[1,2,3,3,3,3],[0,1,2,3,3,3],[0,0,1,2,3,3]])
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(data=offset_array,columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: The simple answer is that you're drawing values from a `Series` containing an index, so the filling occurs in an aligned fashion

Comment: Thank you! that helps me understand why I was getting the results that I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your fill value same as the first row , the we using `shift` + `concat`

```
values_to_fill = pd.Series(np.arange(1,4),index=np.arange(1,4)).reindex(np.arange(1,7)).ffill().astype(int)

pd.concat([values_to_fill.shift(x) for x in range(num_rows)],axis = 1 ).T.fillna(0)
     1    2    3    4    5    6
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Works perfectly in my actual dataset for those rows close to the bottom of the df where length of values to fill is less than available columns after applying shift (offset)

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

res = pd.DataFrame([A] + [[0]*i + A[:-i] for i in range(1, 3)],
                   columns=range(1, 7))

print(res)

   1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  2  3  3  3  3
1  0  1  2  3  3  3
2  0  0  1  2  3  3
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot and tried to up-vote but don't have enough score yet. Your answer actually helped me understand list comprehensions usage better, as it was something I was trying to learn recently. Thanks!